# Drupal: how to move node comments under Read More link?

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, view

My Drupal is displaying a simple custom view, with a nodelist.
The trick is that my view displays comments under nodes in the list.
That is too much for one page and I need to get a list of pure nodes and hide comments under ReadMore link.

I've tried to play with comments settings for my the custom node type I am displaying,
but even if I choose "Display on separate page" - the comments themselves still remain in the main grid.

**How to I move comments under ReadMore link to make them invisible in the grid?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh the joys of theming views.

[View Theming guide](http://drupal.org/node/352970)

This guide should be enough to get you started.

I'd recommend using the views-view-VIEWNAME-field.tpl.php as opposed to writing a theme function.

Hope this helps